# How to add Hamcrest to XCODE?

Tags: xcode, hamcrest

I cannot find the actual hamcrest.framework - only the source code. What steps are to take to actually include into xcode ?
I tried to compile the source code but do not get it connected to a new project I want to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually quite easy. And there is a really great tutorial at Ray Wenderlich's web page ! So check out: http://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift

1) Create an XCode Project (where you want to use Hamcrest)

2) close Xcode

3) Open Terminal-Window and goto path of Xcode Project File

4) (if not already installed) install cocoapods: (this takes quite a while, so don't panic)

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
pod setup --verbose // for verbose output 
pod init  // if it fails with error message you might not be in the correct path)
```

5) Open Pod-File

```
open -a Xcode Podfile
```

6) Edit Pod-File

```
platform :ios, "8.0"
use_frameworks!
```

7) integrate hamcrest as described in github (swifthamcrest)

```
target 'HamcrestDemoTests' do  // name of your File
  pod 'SwiftHamcrest'
end
```

8) Safe File and start installation

```
pod install
```

9) Open your Project using the `.xcworkspace` file

10) import Hamcrest in your TestSuite

```
import XCTest
import Hamcrest

@testable import test

class testTests: XCTestCase {
```

Don't worry about initial errors that it cannot find the module. They will go away after first building the project.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest using cocoapods. It makes adding third-party libraries to your project so much more easy. If you check the OCHamcrest page here: https://github.com/hamcrest/OCHamcrest

they even provide you with instructions on how to set it up.